# How can I use multiple features in basic sentiment analysis in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I've tried to reduce the problem to it's absolute basics. Assume I have data (csv) as such:

```
label,text-column,gender-column,day-column
1,"Sample positive text", female, 1
0,"Sample negative text", female, 3
1,"Another positive comment", male, 2
0,"Angry text sample", male, 7
```

And I have this code that trains on `label` by using BoW (in this case tf-idf) on the `text-column`. I do a 70/30 `train_test_split` and all works well.

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
clf = MultinomialNB()
training_data = pd.read_csv('trainset.csv', delimiter=',')
text_tfidf = vec.fit_transform(training_data['text-column'])
# gen_tfidf = vec.fit_transform(training_data['gender-column'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_tfidf, training_data['label'], test_size = 0.3)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, for the life of me I simply cannot figure out how to use more than one feature. E.g. I want to use, say, both `text-column` and `gender-column` to train the model and see how that impacts accuracy, but I don't understand how to do that!

Am I missing something conceptually important here? Thank you.

Comment: What is the point of using the vectorizer on the gender column? Usually we do that to tranform the tokenized text into vectors. Why don't you just create a big matrix X where the first columns are the vectorized text, then comes the gender column (using sk-learn categorical encoder), and then the day column.

Answer (score 1):

You can one-hot encode the gender column and append it to your tfidf table.

```
gender = pd.get_dummies(training_data['gender-column'])
X = text_tfidf.join(gender)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn has [ColumnTransformer for heterogeneous data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer.html).

Here is a rough code snippet to get you started:

```py
from sklearn.compose                 import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes             import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline                import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing           import OneHotEncoder

pipeline = Pipeline([('union', ColumnTransformer([('tfidf',  TfidfVectorizer(), 'text-column'),
                                                  ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(),   ['gender-column'])])),   
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: `OneHotEncoder` requires 2d data, and so the `ColumnTransformer` needs to specify the column in a list: `['gender-column']`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the code snippet.